# Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application") throws MK_E_UNAVAILABLE when debugging with elevated privileges

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, com-interop, elevated-privileges

This code run without problem in release r debug when Visual studio isn't started as an admin.

```
Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application");
```

However, when I start Vs as administrator and run the same line in debug, I get the following error:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
Operation unavailable (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401E3 (MK_E_UNAVAILABLE))
```

How can I fix this.

Comment: I had a program that sometimes was run with elevated privileges and I got this error too.  Thanks for the question.

Answer (score 12):

I would guess that you are running Visual Studio as Administrator (started via Run as Administrator) while Outlook was opened as user, who was logged in as under Windows logon. So the Visual Studio is running under different user than Outlook client.