# Strange behaviour when using Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application")

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop

In order to start outlook and wait until it's available via Interop I wrote the following Console app:

```
static Outlook.Application outlook;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Profile:");
    var profile = Console.ReadLine();

    var process = Process.GetProcessesByName("Outlook").FirstOrDefault();
    if (process == null)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("outlook.exe", $"/profile \"{profile}\""); // MK_E_UNAVAILABLE appears until I click in the console window
        // ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("outlook.exe"); // Works as expected
        process = Process.Start(startInfo);
    }

    while (outlook == null && !process.HasExited)
    {
        try
        {
            outlook = (Outlook.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application");
            break;
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            outlook = null;
        }
        process.Refresh();
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }

    if (outlook != null)
        Console.WriteLine($"Outlook is running.");

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

I verified in task manager that console app is running under the same user as Outlook does (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23698462/marshal-getactiveobjectoutlook-application-throws-mk-e-unavailable-when-debu)).

The output of the console app is:

```
Vorgang nicht verfügbar. (Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x800401E3 (MK_E_UNAVAILABLE))
Vorgang nicht verfügbar. (Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x800401E3 (MK_E_UNAVAILABLE))
Vorgang nicht verfügbar. (Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x800401E3 (MK_E_UNAVAILABLE))
```

**This message gets repeated until I click into the console window or resize it.** Then output changes to

```
Outlook is running.
```

This does only happen when starting outlook with the *profile* parameter. Without profile parameter the message `Outlook is running.` appears straight after I selected the profile in the Outlook profile dialog.

Can anybody explain what's the reason for this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `WaitForInputIdle()` to force the processing of your application to wait until the message loop has returned to the idle state. When a process with a user interface is executing, its message loop executes every time a Windows message is sent to the process by the operating system. The process then returns to the message loop. A process is said to be in an idle state when it is waiting for messages inside of a message loop. This state is useful, for example, when your application needs to wait for a starting process to finish creating its main window before the application communicates with that window. If a process does not have a message loop, `WaitForInputIdle()` throws an `InvalidOperationException`.

Also I'd suggest adding any delay before checking whether it is running or not.

```
Process.Start(startInfo);
Thread.Sleep(5000);
```

Another possible solution is to use COM Automation with the [Logon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.logon) method which allows specifying the profile name:

```
myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI"); 
myNameSpace.Logon("LatestProfile", Type.Missing , true, true);
```

Comment: I tried the suggested method via Logon:
`ns.Logon(profile, Type.Missing, true, true);
ns.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox).Display();`

Result: Outlook always opens a window with the same profile - no matter which profile I passed to the Logon method. Any idea why?

Comment: Most probably the process has already been started by other applications. Outlook is a singleton, you can't run multiple instances at the same time